# Use <button> element in MyBB forms

Tags: ajax, forms, button, mybb

As the title, I got some problem when trying to use **button** elements in a form, exactly is MyBB forms.

For example, we want to create a new thread right?

So we have these :

- newthread.php (MyBB root)
- newthread template (inside MyBB admincp)

The form will look like this

```
<form action="newthread.php?tid=XX">
...
<button type="submit" name="submit">Post Thread</button>
<button type="submit" name="previewpost">Preview Post</button>
...
</form>
```

And you will know what will happen next, when we click to the Preview Post button, it will submit the form. I change the **type="submit"** => **type="button"** but I don't know how to make the form know that I want to preview the post.

Any help for this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or native JS?

Comment: MyBB use Prototype. But I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I believe all you need to do is specific value for your buttons:

```
<form action="newthread.php?tid=XX">
...
<button type="button" value="submit" name="submit">Post Thread</button>
<button type="button" value="previewpost" name="previewpost">Preview Post</button>
...
</form>
```

Then you can start using your existing javascript code to handle the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('button[name="previewpost"]').click(function () {
    /* do something */
});
```

If you are using native JS:

```
function clickFunction() {
    /* do something */
}
document.getElementsByName('previewpost').onclick(clickFunction);
```

Comment: But the point is I really don't know what I should put in the click function. I'm very new to MyBB :(

Comment: Ah, I understood the question to be: If I click on a button with `type="submit"` the form is submitted, but I don't want that so I changed it to `type="button"` but I don't know how to trigger an event on the button.  Apologies for missunderstanding.  Alas, I cannot write your preview post for you, as I do not know what you would expect the button to do.  However, what you probably want to do is open a popup window or modal with the form's content as the window's content and properly formatted.